# yum couln't fund Mariadb Package on CentoOS 7

Tags: centos, package, mariadb, centos7, yum

I tried to install MariaDB

```
$ sudo yum -y install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

but yum return error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * extras: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * remi-php72: mirror.23media.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
 * updates: mirror.alpix.eu
No package MariaDB-server available.
No package MariaDB-client available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I also add Mariadb repo in  /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
MariaDB.repo is:

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos6-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: 5.5 was released about 9 years ago, and the next major version came out about 7 years ago.  Shoot for something newer.

Answer (score 2):

`http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos6-amd64` in .repo is not match with CentOS 7 this instead:

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos7-amd64/
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

then:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum update
sudo yum -y install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

Comment: I modified the .repo file and executed the instructions above but the same error returns

Comment: @Hamid run `sudo yum repolist all | grep mariadb` check MariaDB repository state

Answer (score 0):

To match case-sensitive names of servers a.k.a. `MariaDB-server` not `mariadb-server`, You **must** have correct mariadb server repos added. Thus - You will also have latest Maria DB server versions (be careful with this, if not intended).

For Centos 7 version worth using official installation manual - much safer and easy: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10-on-centos-7-rhel-7/

```sh
$ cd ~
$ sudo yum install wget
$ wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup
$ chmod +x mariadb_repo_setup
$ sudo ./mariadb_repo_setup
$
$ # Installation
$ sudo yum install MariaDB-server
```